# Максимальное произведение двух целых чисел

Tags: python

> Вам на вход подается N целых чисел. Вам необходимо будет найти среди них два числа, которые дают максимальное произведение. Ответом на задачу будет произведение этих чисел. Массивы использовать в данной задаче запрещено!
>
> Ввод: На первой строке вводится натуральное N, 2 ≤ N ≤ 10000. На последующих N строках вводятся целые числа |ai| ≤ 10000.
>
> Формат вывода: Одно число — максимальное произведение двух чисел.

Попытка найти максимальное и идущее за ним максимальное и умножить их не дает нужный результат, не учитывается одинаковые значения и минусовые значения.

```
n = int(input())
max1 = 0
max2 = 0
if 2 <= n <= 10000:       #
    lst = list(int(input()) for i in range(n))
    for f in lst:
        if f > max1:
            max1 = f
    for j in lst:
        if j > max2 and j < max1:
            max2 = j
max = max1 * max2
print(max)
```

Comment: ты ошибся, тут не сервис по решению домашек

Comment: Отредактируйте свой вопрос, добавив эту информацию и код, тем более, что вы, похоже, видите причины ошибки.

Comment: Кто сказал что я по решению домашек, возникли трудности не могу разобраться вот и задаю вопрос, зачем сразу минусовать я же редактирую.

Comment: надо сразу нормально оформлять и задавать вопрос, тогда и минусовать не будут.

Comment: Не успел все сразу записать, не думал что так быстро реакция будет, по поводу минусовых, это теоретический, да это не учитывал пока согласен. Опыта задавать вопросы еще мало я в основном читаю существующие.

Comment: Не понимаю такое количество минусов. Автор сразу в комменте привел код, потом отредактировал пост, проблема им была продиагностирована верно.

Comment: Поясню минус. Во-первых в вопросе нет вопроса, только изложение. Во-вторых - *"не учитывается одинаковые значения и минусовые значения"* - значит надо учесть (способов множество).

Comment: Интересно получается

Answer (score 1):

Ну в общем, нечто подобное и надо делать. Только нужно поддерживать две пары - наибольших положительных и наименьших отрицательных

Рабочий код:

```
max1 = 0
max2 = 0
min1 = 0
min2 = 0
n = int(input())
for _ in range(n):
    f = int(input())
    if f > 0:
        if f > max1:
            max2 = max1
            max1 = f
        elif f > max2:
            max2 = f
    elif f < 0:
        if f < min1:
            min2 = min1
            min1 = f
        elif f < min2:
            min2 = f
mx = max(max1 * max2, min1 * min2, max1 * min1)
print(mx)
```

Comment: @Эникейщик Автор вообще-то явно говорит, что отрицательные числа - есть. Но его код их существования не учитывает...

Comment: ай, точно, есть. Не на то посмотрел.

Comment: Уберите список. Условие запрещает списки.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy Это я оставил странный код от автора. Входной список вообще не помешает ради ясности задачи

Comment: кстати, тут будет проблема если всего 2 числа (одно больше нуля, второе меньше).

Comment: @pavel Мда, есть такое дело. Похоже, обходится добавлением к выбору минимума ещё пары.

Answer (score 1):

Только изучаю Python, ваша задачка заинтересовала ради тренировки. Вот мое решение без массивов (списков, кортежей, множеств, словарей). Насколько я могу судить, задачу выполняет.

```py
'''
Вам на вход подается N целых чисел. Вам необходимо будет найти 
среди них два числа, которые дают максимальное произведение. 
Ответом на задачу будет произведение этих чисел. Массивы 
использовать в данной задаче запрещено!
'''

vmax = False
vmin = False
multiply = False

while True:
    i = input("Введите цифру или 'q' для завершения: ")

    if i == 'q':
        break

    try:
        i = int(i)
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        print("ERROR! Нужно вводить цифры или 'q' для завершения")
        continue

    if vmax == False and 2 <= i <= 10000:
        # при первом вводе значения оно должно быть между 2 <= N <= 10000
        # учитывая это, можно спокойно оперировать стартом программы при vmax = 0
        vmax = i
        vmin = i
    elif vmax != False and i <= 10000:
        # при втором и далее вводе значений они должны быть <= 10000
        m = i * vmax
        n = i * vmin

        multiply = max(multiply, m, n)

        # if multiply == False:
        #     if m > n:
        #         multiply = m
        #     else:
        #         multiply = n
        # else:
        #     if m > multiply:
        #         multiply = m
        #     elif n > multiply:
        #         multiply = n

        if i > vmax:
            vmax = i

        if i < vmin:
            vmin = i
    else:
        print('ERROR! Нужно вводить цифры 2 <= N <= 10000 для первого значения и <= 10000 для последующих')

print('answer: %d' % multiply)
```

Comment: вы не правы. бОльшим значение будет 1000. в вашем примере.

Comment: @pavel Я не понял вашего комментария. Что бОльшим значением будет 1000? Какие цифры вводите, в каком порядке? Если ввести 2, 9999, 10000 то бОльшим значением будет 10000, но при этом ответ задачи будет 20000

Comment: ??? "Если даже введут значения 2, -10, -100, то большим произведением будет -20" если взять -10 и -100 и перемножить то будет 1000.

Comment: @pavel теперь понял ваш комментарий. да, этот момент я упустил)) каюсь

Comment: надо бежать, но задачку знаю уже как "дорешать", доделаю позже, как будет свободное время

Comment: @pavel подправил решение) тестируйте))